# For some reason my content within an array is not printing out to the screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch

I am currently following a tutorial on PERN stack and whenever I try to print out the contents of an array to the screen to be under **title** and **content**, nothing prints out.

Here is my code where the error relies somewhere within:

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";

const ListBlog = () => {
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]);

  const getBlogs = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/blog');

    const blogArray = await res.json();

    setBlogs(blogArray)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getBlogs();
  }, [])

  console.log(blogs)
  return <Fragment>
    {" "}
    <table className="table mt-5">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Content</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {/* <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
</tr>*/}
     {
       blogs.map(blog => {
         <tr>
           <td>
             {blog.title}
           </td>
           <td>{blog.content}</td>
           <td>Edit</td>
           <td>Delete</td>
         </tr>
       })
     }
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </Fragment>
}

export default ListBlog;
```

I believe the state is causing errors as it is printing out the following:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]0: {post_id: 1, title: 'hi', content: 'howdy'}1: {post_id: 11, title: 'eat', content: 'yogurt'}length: 2[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[object Object],[object Object]
```

I just want to print out the array but for some reason `[Object object]` is printing out as well which may be causing my contents not to print to my localhost page.

Here is what my page looks like when I try to have my contents within the array print underneath **title**, **content**, Edit, and Delete but nothing gets displayed...

[image: Nothing displays on screen]

Comment: You have a few console errors. These are likely why your page isn't working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this happens because you forget to return in `bolgs.map`

```
 {
       blogs.map(blog => {
         return (<tr>
           <td>
             {blog.title}
           </td>
           <td>{blog.content}</td>
           <td>Edit</td>
           <td>Delete</td>
         </tr>)
       })
     }
```

or

```
 {
       blogs.map(blog => (
         <tr>
           <td>
             {blog.title}
           </td>
           <td>{blog.content}</td>
           <td>Edit</td>
           <td>Delete</td>
         </tr>
       ))
     }
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! It is always the small things causing big errors :)

Answer (score 4):

Change curly brackets with normal pharantesis in map

```
{
       blogs.map(blog => (
         <tr>
           <td>
             {blog.title}
           </td>
           <td>{blog.content}</td>
           <td>Edit</td>
           <td>Delete</td>
         </tr>
       ))
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to **return** in map

```
{
   blogs.map(blog => {
     <tr>
       <td>
         {blog.title}
       </td>
       <td>{blog.content}</td>
       <td>Edit</td>
       <td>Delete</td>
     </tr>
   })
}
```

You can write either this

```
{
   blogs.map(blog => {
     return (
      <tr>
        <td>
          {blog.title}
        </td>
        <td>{blog.content}</td>
        <td>Edit</td>
        <td>Delete</td>
      </tr>
     )
   })
}
```

or this

```
{
  blogs.map(blog => ( 
   <tr>
     <td>
       {blog.title}
     </td>
     <td>{blog.content}</td>
     <td>Edit</td>
     <td>Delete</td>
    </tr>
   ))
 }
```